# INotifyPropertyChanged not work after assign new instance

Tags: c#, wpf, inotifypropertychanged

this my base interface:

```
public interface IFlowFunctionType
{
    void RefreshAll();
    void ClearAll();
}
```

and this my base class that implement INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
    public class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
    [field: NonSerialized]
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    #endregion
    #region Protected Methods
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

and this my class implement above interface:

```
    public class M1 : ObservableObject, ISerializable, IFlowFunctionType
{
    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {// some code}

    public void RefreshAll()
    {// some code }

    public void ClearAll()
    {// some code}
}
```

Please tell me why when assign **secondInstance** to **firstInstance** the property of **firstInstance** not fire?

```
 class Main() { 
        public  Main()
        {
            private M1 firstInstance = new M1();
            private M1 secondInstance = new M1();
            DeQueue(firstInstance);
        }
         public void DeQueue( IFlowFunctionType obj)
         {
            obj= secondInstance ;
            obj.RefreshAll();

            DbQueues.Remove(firstOrDefault);
          }
    }
```

Comment: a property of `firstInstance` isn't changing, `firstInstance` _itself_ is changing. if `firstInsance` was a property of another class, you could wire up a property changed event for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No properties of `firstInstance` were changed when you assigned `secondInstance` to it. Your object has no knowledge of when it is assigned, it observes only its own properties.

If you want to observe reassignment, you'd have to assign an `M1` to an object which is itself observable.

```
public class Host : ObservableObject
{
    public M1 Instance {get; set;}
}

...

var host = new Host();
host.Instance = new M1();
host.Instance = new M1(); // Reassigned, Host will see the change.
```

Comment: I'm confused why can't assign `secontInstance?` in my scenario `secondInstance` change  mostly in a loop, after exit from the loop must `secondInstance` assign to  `firstInstance!` do you have suggest?

Comment: `firstInstance` and `secondInstance` are not properties of `M1`, they are *instances* of `M1`. `INotifyPropertyChanged` observes properties,  when you assign a new instance no properties of the original object are actually changed so it doesn't notice anything. I have a suggestion, use another observable object to host your instances of `M1` as I said in my answer.

Comment: Please attention to my new edited code! in `RefreshAll` call for update properties.

Comment: @alireza It doesn't matter! **It's not the same object anymore**, you reassigned it.